# Grails 2.2.0 install-plugin Unresolved Dependancy Error

Tags: grails, plugins

Using GGTS 3.2.0 and working to create a new plugin for a current project. Current Project uses and also has an existing plugin that references the spring-security-kerberos0.2-SNAPSHOT plugin. When I package my plugin and try to install the zip using the local command line I get an error that my plugin has an unresolved Dependency on the Kerberos plugin.

Were on a private network with no internet connection so it cant go out to the web for plugin resolution. We have a local ivy repository that has all of this in it including the Kerberos plugin.

No errors when packaging, only installing. Tried running the Plugin on its own, runs no problem, running the application also shows no errors. To isolate, I created a new blank plugin and tried to install that with the same results. Running the plugin manager on the main project shows the Kerberos plugin installed. Running a dependency report on the plugin shows no dependencies.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it was totally ignoring the ivy references.

Looking at the error it was only trying local locations for the plugin. I copied the plugin Zip and XML to the local plugin cache in grails (c:\grails-2.2.0/lib/org.grails.plugins/spring-security-kerberos) and its happy.

While this solves my immediate issue, the outstanding questions then:

1. why does the plugin installation not look at ivy for resolution? And if that is true, why isnt that reflected in the [plugin documentation](http://grails.org/doc/2.2.x/guide/conf.html#plugindependencies)?
2. why does the error reference the plugin being installed as the issue and not the app that its being installed in-to.